# Three duplicated guest entries posted on form submision

Tags: guest-entries

I was doing some design tweaks to the form today, barely touched coding parts and than I went for a test run to see if it submits an entry.
Everything run as it was on the front end except on the back end I got 3 same entries created with ascending IDs every time an entry is posted.

I was going through and through the form for hours, but ... aaargh!

If anyone has a theory of the issue without seeing the code, post it here please. Otherwise I will submit the code. It's extensive thought.

Comment: Is it one POST request in your network Tab on Front-End?

Comment: Checked it. It seems ok there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site is running through CodeKit compiler connected to MAMP server. This was odd because it has never happened before with same configurations but When I run the site directly from MAMP server the problem disappeared.

But I have no idea why compiler was causing that.